# java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed, while setting the camera parameters

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview

I am making a Camera application. The preview picture was 90 degree rotated. So I changed my code and added the code to set the correct display orientation of the camera. Now when I run the app, it crashes and the error message is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

My surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int w,int h) and surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) methods are as shown.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int w,int h){
    Camera.Parameters mparameters;
    mholder = holder;
    mparameters = mcamera.getParameters();
    mparameters.setPreviewSize(mpreviewsizewidth,mpreviewsizeheight);
    mparameters.setPictureSize(mpreviewsizewidth,mpreviewsizeheight);
    String mCameraFlashMode = mparameters.getFlashMode();
    if(mCameraFlashMode != null){
        mparameters.setFlashMode(mparameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    }
    if(mparameters.getFocusMode() != null) {
        mparameters.setFocusMode(mparameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    Display display = ((WindowManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {
        mparameters.setPreviewSize(mpreviewsizeheight, mpreviewsizewidth);
        mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
    {
        mparameters.setPreviewSize(mpreviewsizewidth, mpreviewsizeheight);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
    {
        mparameters.setPreviewSize(mpreviewsizeheight, mpreviewsizewidth);
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
    {
        mparameters.setPreviewSize(mpreviewsizewidth, mpreviewsizeheight);
        mcamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    mcamera.setParameters(mparameters);
    try {
        mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(mholder);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mcamera.startPreview();
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    mcamera = Camera.open();
    try{
        mcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mcamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    }catch(IOException e){
        mcamera.release();
        mcamera = null;
    }
}
```

Please help me how I can correct my code so that app does not crash while setting the camera parameters, and the preview can be displayed with correct orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to set a preview size which is not supported by Camera object.
You should get the list of supported previewSizes first to check what values you can actually set.

```
List<Camera.Size> sizes = cam.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```